# Run an NUnit test without using the mouse?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, keyboard-shortcuts, testdriven.net

When I want to run 1 test, I always have to right-click the method declaration and click "Run Test".  Is there a way to do this without using the mouse?

Comment: What test runner you are using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A quick google for "TestDriven.NET keyboard shortcuts" gives a few helpful pages.

http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2004/08/30/222447.aspx

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/02/27/testdriven-net-keyboard-shortcut.aspx

Answer (score 2):

See if there are any relevant entries from TestDriven.NET in *Tools* - *Options* - *Keyboard* (for instance, ReSharper adds "ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_ContextRun", which allows to run a unit test method editor cursor is currently in) and bind that to some keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks - I was googling to try and remember the R# command that does that.  It really REALLY should be a default IMO

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Tool=> Options => Keyboard then you can create a new shortcut key to run the unit test for a method or the complete suite. Just pick up the command from the list and assign a key.